# redirect user to home page or disable a submit button if not logged in

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've got a page to submit data into a database and I want to either re-direct them to a different page if they arent logged in OR disable the submit button at the bottom. I'm doing this in my page load event of the page to be denied access.

I've researched and found this in many spots but what exactly am I placing into Session["???"] I'm using the login/register feature provided by asp.net Web Forms

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session[] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to check if there is authenticated user or not

Comment: Thank You! I cant believe I didn't come across this. much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You want to check if the user who made that page requested is authenticated or not. You can do that by checking `User` property of `Request` object like `Request.User.IsAuthenticated`

```
If(!Request.User.IsAuthenticated)
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
```